# Set 'Me.Labelnn.BackColor' with a for nn=... loop in a report with many labels

Tags: ms-access, vba, controls, report

I have a report which is like an hourly schedule for a whole week. Each cell in the schedule is 1 day for 1 machine. Each column is one of 7 machines. Thus, a row consists of 7 day cells. So far so good, but each day needs 18 rows of text (a Memo field) and - each row needs to be colorized. I've created 18 labels numbered Label33 and up, for each of the 7 columns.

I'm setting their BackColor with a pretty large case statement of 7 cases and 18 x Labelnn.Backcolor=aColor in each case.

However, I'd like to replace this with something that forms the `control_name="Label" & n`n, and do something like `Me.control_name.BackColor=aColor`.

Possible? How? (No, considering how flexible VBA-Access is I haven't tried the above yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cody Gray is correct but this is not helpful if you do not know what a control array is.

The following is Excel VBA but I have done the same with Access VBA but not recently.  I think the syntax is the same but I do not guarantee it.

I created a workbook, inserted a form, pulled a selection of controls onto it and then ran the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestControls()

  Dim InxC As Long

  Load UserForm1

  With UserForm1
    For InxC = 0 To .Controls.Count - 1
      Debug.Print .Controls(InxC).Name
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

The output to the immediate window was:

```
Label1
CommandButton1
ComboBox1
CommandButton2
OptionButton1
```

You can see that `Label1.xxx` is exactly the same as `.Controls(0).xxx`.  I name my controls systematically so I can run code like:

```
  With UserForm1
    For InxC = 0 To .Controls.Count - 1
      If Mid(.Controls(InxC).Name,1,5) = "lblXx" Then
        ' Code to set properties of all lblXx controls
      End If
    Next
  End With
```

I use this functionality most when I do not know how many of a particularly type of control I need.  I create 10, say, of them which is more than I will ever need and make them all invisible.

At run time, I make those I need visible and set their top and left properties as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cody Gray. Use the **Control Arrays**.

Here is a link which will help you

http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Though Tony has given you a relatively easy way to do it but there are instances where you might add or delete a control or simply mess up on the sequence. Also there are instances when you simply cannot leave the label as `Label1`. You might be adding some text to it so that it signifies something...

In such a scenario use `TypeOf` instead of `Name`

For example

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is Label Then
            Debug.Print ctl.Name
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```